# Чи є калькою: втратити свідомість?

Tags: вживання-слів

Ще в школі нас вчили, що *втратити свідомість* - це калька, і правильно говорити *зомлів* чи *знепритомнів*

> Адже в нашій мові свідомість – то не стільки здатність людини орієнтуватися в довколишній дійсності, скільки відчуття своєї належності до інших людей та обов’язку перед ними. Національна, громадянська свідомість.  …  Таких словосполучень ми не знайдемо ні в українській класиці, ні у фольклорі, ні в сучасній народній мові. До звороту бути непритомним є паралель бути (лежати) без пам’яті. Так само до слів опритомніти, прийти до тями маємо відповідники прийти до пам’яті, очуняти. Значення “допомогти непритомному” передається висловами приводити до притомності (до пам’яті), опритомніти.
>
> [Уроки державної мови (з газети «Хрещатик»)](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53399/25910.html)

Останнім часом, постійно чую, як втрачають свідомість герої фільмів. Також ця фраза буває в новинах. Це помилки? Чи цей вираз більше не вважається калькою?

Comment: «To lose consciousness» - це англійський вираз, і російська явно зкалькувала з нього або ж відповідного німецького виразу «das Bewusstsein verlieren», який теж дослівно означає «втратити свідомість».

Comment: Саме так: це калька. Якщо йдеться про "обморок".

Comment: Схоже: [Що не так із «впасти замертво»?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2576/)

Answer (score 17):

[CУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/svidomistj) знає вираз "втратити свідомість":
"Утрачати (утратити) свідомість (притомність) — непритомніти, зомлівати."

[СУМ-20](http://test.ulif.org.ua:8000/expl/Entry/index?wordid=142449&page=561) фактично скопіював це визначення.

Відповідно, цей вираз, на жаль, є нормативним.

З іншого боку, широко визнана праця [Як ми говоримо](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/svidomist-pamyat-tyama-prytomnist) вважає цей вираз зовсім неправильним. З цієї праці бачимо копії у згаданій статті й у багатьох інших.

Також не бачу причин користуватися "втратити свідомість", коли існує аж два згаданих коротших і влучніших слова "знепритомніти" й "зомліти".

Comment: Ось яскравий приклад закостенілості академічних видань радянського часу. Опиратись на них нерідко ознаяає калічити нашу мову.

Comment: Цілковито погоджуюся, дозволив собі у відповіді навіть написати "на жаль" :)
Але ж, на превеликий жаль, це факт - те, що пишуть у цих закостенілих, а часто відверто халтурних словниках - є нормативним... :'( Я дуже сподівався на СУМ-20 і навіть купив перший том для підтримки проекту... Далі не купував )

Comment: і дійсно, адже 'втратити свідомість' по сенсу ближче до 'втратити тяму', *тлумачний* словник фіксує використання оборотів у певному значенні і, як на мене, йому більш притаманна довідкова функція, а не, на наше щастя, функція поради щодо літературного стилю.

Comment: Додам ще кілька фактів. «Сучасний російсько-український, україно-російський словник» («Ранок», 2005) ігнорує вживання слова «свідомість» у даному значенні. У книзі «Мова чудова» (О. Уліщенко, Vivat, 2016) визнається існування вислову «втрачати свідомість», проте зворотня дія називається грубою калькою з російської. http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/пам_яті-тяма/ — тут радять не вживати цього вислову і підкреслюють, що «свідомість» — це властивість мозку, а не стан притомності. Сполучення «без сознания» двозначне, перекладати треба за контекстом.

Comment: Вони не халтурні. Вони  складалися саме таким чином, щоб демонструвати тільки дуже схожі на російські лексеми. Взагалі існувала програма зі "зближення мов", за якою українська з часом мала стати чи то зовсім схожою на російську, чи то просто російською ) це не жарти, на жаль.

Comment: @OlenaLisovs'ka Ваша правда. Я більше про СУМ-20, що бездумно скопіював майже все з СУМ-11 і лише доповнив якимись словами... Чи, гадаєте, віне переслідує ту ж мету?..

Answer (score 0):

З точки зору біології цей вислів є цілком нормативним. Якщо ви хочете пояснити значення терміна "зомління", ви можете вживати словосполучення "втратити свідомість", це буде абсолютно правильно. Ви плутаєте сам термін і значення цього терміну. Рос. потерять сознание, українською - втратити свідомість. А ось сам процес втрати свідомості називається непритомність або зомління (рос. обморок). Тобто рос. упасть в обморок - укр. знепритомніти. Рос. потерять сознание - укр. втратити свідомість. І де тут схожість? Кожне слово має свій відповідник. Що за нісенітниця? Хіба в українській мові не можна вживати слова в переносному значенні? Слово "втратити" може мати не тільки пряме значення, можна "втратити" не тільки якийсь предмет, але і пам'ять, мову, свідомість і т.д.   [image]

[image]

Comment: В значенні, про яке каже Iryna це калька.