# Що не так із «впасти замертво»?

Tags: стилістика

В [статті Олека Веремка-Бережного на LB.ua](//ukr.lb.ua/culture/2015/09/15/316023_literaturna_reviziya_rosiyske.html) (також у [його власному блозі](//hardreadblog.wordpress.com/2017/05/08/rosiyske-vtorhnennya-do-perekladiv/)), що критикує якість деяких перекладів українською мовою, є такий фрагмент:

> До цього можна вже було би не додавати про навички персонажів «смутно розуміти», «змазувати» замість «намастити» [«намащувати»], «стояти у віконця» чи «падати замертво».

Хоч я розумію, в чому полягають стилістичні помилки перших прикладів у переліку («[смутно](http://sum.in.ua/s/smutno)» і «[смутний](http://sum.in.ua/s/smutnyj)» в українській мові позначають перш за все щось пов'язане зі *[смутком](http://sum.in.ua/s/smutok)*, тому російське «смутно понимает» треба перекладати як «неясно розуміє»; «[змазувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=36805&page=1158)» особисто в мене більш асоціюється з нанесенням мазуту на технічні агрегати чи із розфукусуванням зображення, для нанесення крему на людську шкіру більше підходить «намастити»; «[в](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=6305&page=230)» і «[у](http://sum.in.ua/s/u)» в значенні «біля» — застарілі), але проблеми в «падати замертво» не бачу.

Таке словосполучення наводить і «Словник української мови» в 20 томах:

> **[ЗА́МЕРТВО](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=134350&page=1000)**, *присл*. Так, як мертвий, як неживий; без ознак життя.
>
> - *Стало невидане чудо: всі гади разом зі старшим Змієм попадали замертво*
>     (з легенди);
> - *Стріла влучила юнакові в груди, і він замертво впав на узбіччя*
>     (О. Авраменко, В. Авраменко);
> - *Батько помер від серцевого нападу.. Поставив грітися чайник і впав замертво, коли Олеся ще була на роботі* (В. Кожелянко).

То:

1. Чи є справді проблема у словосполученні «впасти/падати замертво»? Чи, може, автори статті помилилися? Або ж вони насправді теж не бачать проблеми в самій фразі, просто навели її як приклад маркеру того, що текст перекладався на українську через російську, а не з оригіналу (тобто наявність фрази не робить текст неправильним, але збільшує ймовірність того, що це переклад з російської)?
2. Якщо фраза неправильна, або стилістично не найкраща, або справді навіює на думки про переклад з російської — то які є кращі альтернативи? (Які б не мали стилістичних чи інших проблема, або не навіювали думки, що цей текст явно перекладався з російської.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Інші джерела, що включають декілька словників, чи просто словники, довідники  — [Muscovian](http://r2u.org.ua/s?scope=&highlight=on&w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)+[English](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=drop%20dead&dicts=all&highlight=on) 2 [Ukrainian](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE&highlight=on), [Грінченко](http://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch/), [Академічний тлумачний словник (1970–1980)](http://sum.in.ua) (хоча є в одному [прикладі](http://sum.in.ua/s/prynosyty)), [Браунський корпус](https://github.com/brown-uk/corpus/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) — не включають цього слова.

Натомість деякі з них, [московсько-український  словник сталих виразів](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/everyfile.php?transfer=folders/ze/zamjrtvo.html), [словник мовних покручів](http://torba.etnoua.info/files/Oleksa-Tyhyj_Slovnyk-movnyh-pokruchiv_VOvsijenko_2009.pdf) · [Олекси Тихого](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [московсько-український словник](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=aeBHAQAAMAAJ&q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE&redir_esc=y)  · [Євгена Тимченка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%84%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) рекомендують використовувати **як мертвий**, **без духу** (**трупно**).

Окрім [згаданого](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=134350&page=1000) · [словника української мови у 20 томах](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%83_20_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85), є ще [ортографічний словник української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/35/53399/84743.html), що включає це слово без пояснень.

Результат перевірки [корпусу ЛКЛ ІФ КНУ](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx?l1=209) вказуює, що слово не популярне, вживається переважно після 1991 року (перелік нижче) й пітверджує критику Олека Веремка-Бережного. Майже те саме вказує [корпус Лейпцизького університету](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE&corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014).

- *цілоденною працею, **замертво** падали на соломʼяні підстилки* ([Олесь Бердник](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [1967](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=12284))
- *мамця звалилася геть **замертво**, а невситиме черевце* ([Микола Братан](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [2008](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=12509))
- *що було розпласталася **замертво** на порозі* ([Євген Пашковський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%84%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [1993](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=17869))
- *острівок, куди **замертво** плюхнулися дві качки* ([Євген Пашковський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%84%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [1993](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=17874))
- *подушечках лап, **замертво** падав на солом* ([Євген Пашковський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%84%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [1992](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=17955))
- *доки не падала **замертво**, та ще й* ([Марія Ряполова](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0), [2010](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=23722))
- *вiн i впав **замертво** на руки козацького гетьмана* (Юрій Сорока, [2012](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=28265))
- *за серце і **замертво** упав на підлогу* (Лефевр, [2013](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=28510))
- *а я впала **замертво** на свою* ([Галина Тарасюк](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=29181), [2009](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=29181))
- *темною фортецею, **замертво**, непорушне, взялась* ([Григорій Тютюнник](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [1960](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=31294))
- *Грім звалив її **замертво**!* ([Марія Матіос](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D0%BE%D1%81_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0), [2006](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=34842))
- *Віталік падає **замертво**, ми відносимо його* ([Артем Чех](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%85), [2008](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=34855))
- *вовк не впав **замертво** на порозі ферми* ([Юрій Щербак](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A9%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%AE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [1986](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=35346))
- *інколи падали чомусь **замертво** та колючий дріт* (Артур Сіренко, [2012](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=35864))
- *промінь антени падали **замертво** на землю* (Артур Сіренко, [2014](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=35915))
- *єнотовидний собака впав **замертво*** (Голда, [2006](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=27763))
- *один валиться **замертво**, а другий падає* (Ковалевський, [2002](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=27896))
- *змій впав **замертво*** ([2000](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=29326))
- *кулю і впав **замертво*** (Володимир Думанський, [2010](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=29783))
- *стогону генералісимус упав **замертво*** (Сергій Махун, [2016](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=33930))
- *порог, упал **замертво*** ([2017](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=44854))

[Паралельний корпус](http://www.ruscorpora.ru/search-para-uk.html) · [Інституту московської мови](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%92._%D0%92._%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%9D) імені [Віктора Віноградова](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) вказує, що українська [не заохочує](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mysent=&mysize=9383923&mysentsize=919437&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=para&sort=gr_tagging&env=alpha&mycorp=%28lang%3A%22ukr%22%20%7C%20lang_trans%3A%22ukr%22%29&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E7%E0%EC%E5%F0%F2%E2%EE&gramm1=&flags1=&sem1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&flags2=&sem2=) (перелік нижче) фразеологізм з московської — „упасть замертво“.

1. [Володимир Малик](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80_%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). [Фірман султана](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB) (1969)

   - *Порубаний шаблями, окольничий Ржевський упав **мертвий** на гарячу, мов присок, землю.*
   - *Залитый кровью, он **замертво** упал на горячую, как зола, землю.* (В. Доронин, Е. Цветков, 1989)
2. [А. Н. Стругацкий](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%90%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [Б. Н. Стругацкий](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). [Обитаемый остров](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2_(%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD)) (1967–1968)

   - *Если бы Генерал пустил меня в одиночку, я бы сразу размозжил себе обе ноги и сейчас валялся бы **замертво** на этих гнусных ехидных колышках…*
   - *Якби Генерал пустив мене самого, я б умить роздробив собі обидві ноги і нині **валявся** б на цих мерзенних єхидних кілочках…* (С. С. Павловський)
3. [Роман Іваничук](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%83%D0%BA_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). [Мальви](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%B8_(%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD)) (1965–1967)

   - *Ви всі, ви всі проти мене, всі зрадники! — султан схопив шаблю, подаровану послами, і, не виймаючи її з піхов, сягнув нею по черепу свого єдиного дорадника. Недим упав на землю **мертвий**, і в цю мить спамʼятався Ібрагім. Він вклякнув біля нього, тер долонею по синьому басамані на скроні і безпорадно розглядався довкола.*
   - *Вы все, вы все против меня, все изменники! — Султан выхватил из ножен саблю, подаренную послами, рубанул ею по голове единственного советника. Недым **замертво** повалился наземь. Ибрагим в оцепенении замер над трупом друга.* (К. Трофимов, 1988)
4. [Микола Руденко](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). Чарівний бумеранг (1962–1966)

   - *Мічман не встиг договорити, як знову заляскотіли постріли. Двоє мідношкірих воїнів упали **мертві**. Володимир скинув мічманку.*
   - *Но не успел он договорить, как снова защелкали выстрелы. И двое меднокожих воинов упали **замертво**. Владимир снял мичманку.* (З. Крахмальникова, 1968)
5. [Остап Вишня](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BF_%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F). Бенгальський тигр (1945–1956)

   - *Лунає постріл, за ним лунає одчайдушний крик, і падає **мертвий** тубілець із підрозділу, що наганяє звіра на високопоставлених у куренях охотників.*
   - *Звучит выстрел, за ним звучит отчаяннейший крик, и туземец, гоняющий зверя на высокопоставленных в шалашах охотников, падает **замертво**.* (Е. Весенин, 1954–1958)
6. [Н. А. Островский](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). Как закалялась сталь (ч. 1) (1930–1934)

   - *Я мучился меньше других: после первых же ударов свалился **замертво** на пол, но другие покрепче были.*
   - *Я мучився менше, ніж інші: після перших же ударів упав **непритомний** на підлогу, але інші були міцніші.* (Виктор Петровьский, 1974)
7. [Михайло Коцюбинський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). [Тіні забутих предків](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2_(%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)) (1912)

   - *Не падають **трупом**, як плохі вівці, а твердо стоять на тоненьких ногах.*
   - *Они не падают **замертво**, как слабые овцы, а твердо стоят на тонких ногах.* (Н. Ушаков, 1965)
8. [Ольга Кобилянська](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%AE%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0). [Земля](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)) (1901)

   - *В неї ж волосся біле, як сніг… їй здавалося, що якби був побережник дав їй тоді лише один поличник, вона була б зараз упала на місці **трупом**.*
   - *У нее волосы белые, как снег… Ей казалось, что если бы сторож тогда хоть раз ударил ее, она тут же свалилась бы **замертво**.* (В. Тарсис, Е. Егорова, 1948)
9. [Михайло Коцюбинський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). [Дорогою ціною](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%8E_%D1%86%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8E) (1901)

   - *Коли б у неї був серп або ніж, вона різала б його доти, поки б він не поліг увесь або вона сама не впала **трупом**.*
   - *Если б у нее был серп или нож, она срезала бы его до тех пор, пока не лег бы весь или она сама не упала бы **замертво**.* (Н. Ушаков, 1965)
10. [Іван Франко](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%AF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). [Борислав сміється](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%94%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) (1881)

    - *Бенедьо лиш раз зойкнув і впав, **мов неживий**, на землю.*
    - *Бенедя вскрикнул и **замертво** упал на землю.* (Е. Мозольков, Б. Турганов, 1940)
11. [Пантелеймон Кулиш](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%88_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). [Черная рада](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0_(%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD)), Хроника 1663 года (1846–1857)

    - *Не успѣла погоня доскакать до провала, какъ Петро и Кирило Туръ нанесли въ одно и то же мгновеніе другъ другу въ грудь по такому удару, что оба повалились **замертво**.*
    - *Доскакує Сомко із Шрамом до провалля, аж Кирило Тур із Петром дали один одному в груди так щиро, що й повалились обидва, **як снопи**.* ([Пантелеймон Кулiш](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%88_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), 1857–1858)
12. [Григорій Квітка-Основʼяненко](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). [Конотопська відьма](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0) (1833)

    - *Тiльки таки що другий пiвень крикнув, тут Явдоха що є духу ускочила в хату i впала, **мов нежива**.*
    - *Только-таки что другие петухи крикнули, тут Явдоха, что есть духу, вскочила в хату и упала **замертво**.* ([Г. Квитка-Основьяненко](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), 1833–1843)

Comment: те саме із *заживо*

Comment: Хм, цікаво, я тільки зараз дізнався, що «замертво» означає «наче мертвий». Я до цього думав, що «замертво» буквально означає «мертвим». Тобто якщо герой «впав замертво» — він ще, виходить, може піднятися? (І впасти замертво можна, виходить, від дрібної причини — а не від летальної?)

Comment: Знайшов [ще цікавий словник](//books.google.com/books?id=aeBHAQAAMAAJ&q=замертво).

Comment: @Sasha, [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кліффорд_Сімак) пропонує такий варіант перекладу повісті Кліффорда Сімака (Саймака) "Drop Dead"  - *"Впасти мертвим"* (рос. - "Упасть замертво") .

Comment: Так, російське "замертво" - це не "мертвим", а "наче мертвим", власне, це застаріле стилізоване "знепритомніти".

Comment: @Follower, мені здається, що *впасти мертвим* має це саме переносне значення - *як мертвий*, а не буквально *мертвий*. Дуже часто можна почути "*Я мертва(ий)*", (від втоми, від спеки тощо).

Comment: @OlenaLisovs'ka, згідно з [російською Wiktionary](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/замертво#.D0.97.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5) (і наведеною цитатою Лермонтова), воно може позначати і «мертвим», і «наче мертвим». Причому вони вважають «мертвим» основним, а «наче мертвим» — переносним. Хоча, може, це й неправда (Wiktionary може редагувати кожен).

Answer (score 6):

Поважаючи [думку і аргументацію Follower](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2577) і визнаючи, що він, можливо, має рацію, все-таки підсумую тут аргументи за існування слова:

1. Слово «замертво» є в словниках:

   1. [Сучасний (2010–…) тлумачний «Словник української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=134350&page=1000), виданий під егідою Українського мовно-інформаційного фонду Національної академії наук України (це наведено в самому запитанні).
      <sub>Відсутність цього слова в [його попереднику («Словнику української мови» в 11 томах 1970-х років)](http://sum.in.ua/) не вважаю аргументом, тому що: по-перше, словник в 20 томах цілком є наступником словника в 11 томах (наслідує значну частину змісту і певні радянізми), тож дивно дивитися в старий словник, якщо є новий (а якщо відкидати новий через радянський присмак, то й старий тим більше); по-друге, на мою думку найімовірніше, це слово не внесли в старий словник не тому, що вважали його нелітературним, а просто забули/загубили (очевидно, таке трапляється — жоден словник не містить абсолютно всі слова), і те, що це слово вжите в цитаті, наведеній у двох інших статтях ([«оглушений»](http://sum.in.ua/s/oghlushenyj), [«приносити»](http://sum.in.ua/s/prynosyty)), по-моєму, лише доводить це.</sub>
   2. [«Словники України on-line» 2008 року](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) (також [офіційний вхід](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)), теж опубліковані під егідою УМІФ.
2. Слово «замертво» вживалося (хоча й рідко) з другої половини XIX століття, зокрема такими письменниками, як Григорій Тютюнник і Олесь Гончар, і таким мовознавцем, як Юрій Шевельов:

   1. Іван Рудченко «Народныя южнорусскія сказки. Выпускъ 1» (1869, Київ, з архіву Стенфордського Університету):

      > От тілько що хотів Иван до колодезя пидступить — аж тут як зачхали зміі, то з носів йіх аж дим пійшов, а Иван упав замертво, дай лежить.
   2. Андрій Молодченко «Веселка» (1887, Львів):

      > На решті вінъ упавъ зъ высокості замертво, прыпавъ до землі; болізно йому, а такы здайеться вырятувався!
   3. «Казки братів Грімм: в чотирьох томах» (1919, Київ — Відень, «Вернигора»):

      > Вона хотіла помститися за те, що її не було покликано на свято, і тому, ні з ким не поздоровкавшись і, навіть, ні на кого не глянувши, вона голосно вигукнула: «Як буде королівні п'ятнадцять літ, то вколеться вона об веретено й звалиться замертво!»
   4. Григорій Тютюнник «Вир» (1961):

      > Із-за Беевої гори вилізла хмара, стала у воді темною фортецею, замертво, непорушне, взялась димами, закурілась.
   5. Олесь Гончар «Таврія» (1964; ця цитата наводиться в СУМ-11):

      > Останнім приплив із своїми краянами Федір Андрійка, відчайдушний шибайголова з розірваною губою, який щоліта бився на сільських храмах з хутірськими глитаєнками, а іноді і сам падав замертво, оглушений залізним шворнем, так що приносили його потім старій Андріячисі в рядні.
   6. Юрій Шерех (превдонім Шевельова a.k.a. Шнайдера — відомого мовознавця) «Шоста симфонія Миколи Куліша» зі збірки «Не для дітей» (1964, Нью-Йорк, «Пролог»):

      > Образ людства — це кошмарний образ гусей, що з'їли вишні з вишнівки, зробилися п'яні, попадали замертво, були общипані, але прокинулися — і от — «уранці чує: ґел-ґел-ґел. Ідуть усі до порога, голодні з похмілля і голі. Ха-ха-ха! Голі! Чому ви не смієтеся, чорт забирай!»

Ну але чи варто це слово використовувати, чи вважати його невдалим (не рідним) — вирішує вже кожен для себе.

<sub>P.S.: Окрім згаданих вище альтернатив «**мертвим**», «**як/наче/неначе мертвий/неживий**», «**без духу**», «**трупно**», «**трупом**» випадково натрапив на неочікуваний для мене варіант «[намертво](http://sum.in.ua/s/namertvo)». Хоча це слово вживається здебільного в переносному значенні («міцно, що не можна роз'єднати») або як обставина при дієслові активної дії нападника, а не реакції постраждалого (наприклад «бити намертво») — але іноді цей прислівник вживають і стосовно реакції постраждалого (Остап Вишня, «Ружжо»: «Я стріляв так просто, щоб наполохати, а він намертво»; Василь Сологуб, «Сотвори себе», 1983: «У цю мить сталося неймовірне: мовчун у поліцайськїй формі сіконув із свого автомата, і паліяка намертво впав у сінях»; Олександр Мироненко, «Україна: початок великого шляху», 2007: «Старий ойкнув і впав намертво додолу»). Хоча, на відміну від «замертво», це слово (коли вживається не в менсі «міцно»), здається, означає лише смерть у прямому сенсі (а не просто «наче мертвий»).</sub>

Answer (score -2):

В московській мові багато запозичень з української. Я вже мовчу про англійську, яка всотує в себе все, що підходить, і не переймається. Мова - живий організм, і не треба впадати в недоречний та шкідливий пуризм. Якщо український еквівалент (в тому числі й неологізм) в стилістичному, звуковому й конотаційному сенсах програє своєму візаві, котрий нормально вписується в українську мовну канву, то не бачу в запозиченні нічого поганого.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Зауважте, що цей сайт — не chat board, і тому абстрактні роздуми тут мають місце лише тоді, коли вони грають допоміжну роль для формування основної відповіді, яка має ґрунтуватися **на наукових фактах** і бути підтверджена **посиланнями** на поважні джерела. Для порівняння, перегляньте, будь ласка, сусідню відповідь — вона відповідає нашим вимогам до змісту і оформлення.

Comment: Володимир Горбатько, а я з Вами згоден. Мені теж здається, що слово має право на існування (тим більше, що прийняте словниками НАНУ). Але варто підкріпити Вашу позицію якимись доказами (бо інакше виходить просто Ваше слово проти чийогось ще).